# How to generate random double with RandomNumberGenerator in .NET 6

Tags: random, .net-6.0

In .NET 6, as RNGCryptoServiceProvider has been marked as obsolete in .NET, I'm trying to find an alternative to generate evenly distributed random doubles (between 0 inclusive and 1 exclusive). I need something reliable both running on Windows or Linux.

I've found this online and I'd like to know if it reliable and how can I test the distribution.

```
// Step 1: fill an array with 8 random bytes
byte[] bytes = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(8);

// Step 2: bit-shift 11 and 53 based on double's mantissa bits
ulong ul = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0) / (1 << 11);
return ul / (double)(1UL << 53);
```

Answer (score 0):

`RNGCryptoServiceProvider` inherits from `RandomNumberGenerator` so the methods remain the same. The following snippet works since .NET Core 2.0

```
var rng=RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
byte[] bytes = rng.GetBytes(8);
```

I suspect the real problem is that the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` constructor was used instead of the `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` or `RandomNumberGenerator.Create(string)`factory methods.